# Redux: How to add item to Array, and return Array with all items added

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, bitcoin

I'm using Redux in my React App, currently only have 1 reducer at the moment for a Portfolio of cryptocurrencies. Just an array of coins.

When I dispatch my ADD_COIN action the first time I get back an Array of 1 object which is expected. However when I call dispatch again on another coin it returns the Array again, but still only with 1 item, the latest coin that was selected.

How would this need to be re-written to return back the updated Array with all added coins?

**1st coin added**
[image]

**2nd coin added, expected to see an Array with 2 objects:**
[image]

#### index.js the store code

```
const store = createStore(reducer, compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
));
```

#### The reducer file

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import portfolio from './portfolio'

export default combineReducers({
    portfolio
});
```

#### The actions file

```
import * as R from 'ramda'
import * as api from '../../services/api'
import { addToPortfolio, getPortfolio } from '../../services/coinFactory'

export const ADD_COIN = 'ADD_COIN'

export function addCoin(coin) {
    return dispatch =>
        api.getCoin(coin)
            .then((res) => addToPortfolio(R.head(res.data)))
            .then((portfolio) => dispatch(add(portfolio)));
}

//action creator
export function add(portfolio) {
    return {
        type: ADD_COIN,
        portfolio
    }
}
```

#### The Portfolio reducer

```
import { ADD_COIN } from './actions'

const initialState = [];

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_COIN:
            return action.portfolio;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

#### Finally the coinFactory.js which has the Array

```
import * as R from 'ramda'
import local_coins from '../coins.json'

export const storage = {
    coins: local_coins,
    portfolio: []
};

export const getPortfolio = () => storage.portfolio;

export const addToPortfolio = (coin) => {
    storage.portfolio.push(coin);
    return getPortfolio();
};
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of mutating your initialState with `.push`, "copy" your last state into meaningful new state

```
import { ADD_COIN } from './actions'

const initialState = [];

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_COIN:
            return [...state, action.portfolio]; // same as state.concat(action.portfolio)
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm strange, I'm running into the same original problem now... an Array with 1 item, debugging

Comment: are you still using this function `addToPortfolio` ?

Comment: Oh I think I see... `storage.portfolio` returns an array

Comment: so you're trying to "add a coin" but you're sending the entire portfoilio, so your new state is an array with a portfolio array inside of it

Comment: No, I'm no longer using that function... seriously have no idea what's going on now. I may push and link my repo.

Comment: cool if it's open I'll take a look. join our slack for further help. ping @alex-wilmer http://slack.torontojs.com/

Comment: Yeah mind a look? You can pull it here: https://github.com/CoinHover/coinhover.io just `npm run dev` the reducer code is in the `src/reducer` folder.

Comment: Ah wait, the code is working... I was stepping through the reducer and I see it working too... problem is in my Portfolio component, `this.state.assets` almost done

Comment: ok np. I don't mind helping you further, I would recommend joining that slack channel. very active react group there

Comment: Sure I'll join! Btw please let me know what you think of my Redux logic, I'll push what I just updated in a sec

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, I was incorrectly trying to use 2 different design patterns. The factory pattern with Redux... not actually bad, but it made me make this mistake.

```
import { ADD_COIN } from './actions'

const initialState = [];

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_COIN:
            return initialState.push(action.portfolio);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**initialState** is suppose to be my Portfolio array.
So in the case of action ADD_COIN, I need to push it into that array, not the one from my factory (though I guess I could use the factory Array and set it to initialState)

**Then in my actions I sent out just the coin, not a coin already inside of another Array.**

```
import * as R from 'ramda'
import * as api from '../../services/api'

export const ADD_COIN = 'ADD_COIN'

export function addCoin(coin) {
    return dispatch =>
        api.getCoin(coin)
            .then((res) => R.head(res.data))
            .then((remote_coin) => dispatch(add(remote_coin)));
}

// action creator
export function add(portfolio) {
    return {
        type: ADD_COIN,
        portfolio
    }
}
```

Now the state of the Portfolio Array updates correctly

[image]

[image]

If someone has a better more description answer to this I'll mark their answer instead of this.

Comment: @azium yes I am, do you recommend a better alternative?

Comment: yes `.concat` or `[...state, coin]`. redux specifically says to not mutate state anywhere

Comment: also you're adding an item to intitialState, not state, so you can only ever have one item in your array at most, which must be a mistake

Comment: Ah that is better, do you want to post your answer with that spread operator? I don't like checking my own answers, but others.